# How to add a rectangle to specified axis in D3

Tags: d3.js

I have a zoomable area plot done in D3, which works well. Now I am trying to add a rectangle to the specified location along x-axis in the middle of the plot. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do that. "rect" element is specified using absolute (x,y) of the plot and so when using zooms it stays in the same position.

So I was wondering if there is a way to tie "rect" to the axis when plotting, so that it benefits from all the zoom and translate behaviour or do I need to manually edit the x,y,width and length of the rectangle according to translation as well as figuring out where the corresponding x and y coordinates are on the graph? I am trying to use "rect" because it seems the most flexible element to use.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are doing the zooming, but I am guessing you are changing the parameters of the scales you use with your axis? You should be able to use the same scales to place your rectangle.

If you are starting with plot coordinates then maybe using the invert function on the scale will help (available at least for quantitive scales), e.g. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_invert

You should be able to take initial plot coordinates and invert them to determine data coordinates that can then move with changes in the scale.

If the scale is linear you can probably invert the length and width too, but you will have to compute offsets if your domain does not include 0. Easiest is to compute the rectangle's end points, something like:

```
var dataX0 = xScale.invert(rect.x);
var dataX1 = xScale.invert(rect.x + rect.width);
var dataWidth = dataX1 - dataX0;
```

If you have the data in axes coordinates already you should be able to do something like:

```
var rectData = [{x: 'April 1, 1999', y: 10000, width: 100, height:100}];
svg.selectAll('rect.boxy')
    .data(rectData)
    .enter().append('rect').classed('boxy', true)
    .style('fill','black');

svg.selectAll('rect.boxy')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(new Date(d.x));} )
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.y);})
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width;} )
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height;} );
```

Based on the example you shared where x and y (as functions) are the scales the axes are based on.

Comment: I am using the pan and zoom example from the D3.js (http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html) with slightly modified translate. I was hoping there is a way to draw rectangle using axis coordinates not absolute (x,y) of the plot area.

Comment: Edited to show how to assign rect position from the scale if you have non-absolute (i.e. data) coordinates. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Perfect! Almost exactly what I wanted, except I don't need to invert when working out the width of the box. Otherwise it gets smaller as I zoom in and larger as I zoom out. I'll add the change to the answer, thanks a lot though!